# InnerHTML/TextContent Works Sporadically

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, innerhtml

For the last couple of days I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my site (https://hungry-goldberg-git.netlify.app/). The products, classes, gallery and contact pages all have a repeating header that pulls from the file (pageheader.html). The strange thing is about 60% of the time when I load the site and click through the links the page header displays properly. Other times, the pager header will show on 2 or 3 of the pages, but not the others. Another interesting thing is I am able to click through all of the links and see the headers the first time, when I click on the link again the header goes away (ex. I click products > classes > gallery > contact > classes... I will not see the text in the header again).

Through looking at into the Developer tools I see the [property is set to null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kydl.png). I know this happens when the script tries to execute before the element is rendered on the page, but I can't figure out how to correct this. I already have `<script src="/js/main.js"></script>` at the bottom of my HTML right before the closing body tag. I also have my opening body tag to `<body onload="titleInjection()">`in hopes that would allow the JavaScript to wait until my page was fully loaded before it ran. However, that didn't work.

I also tried `<script src="/js/main.js" defer></script>` at the bottom, but that didn't work either. Can anyone possibly shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Just in case you would like to see all of the code I am using I'm including portions of it below.

**classes.html**

```
  <!--===================== Page Title =====================-->

  <header id="pageheader"></header>
```

**pageheader.html**

```
<div class="w-full mx-auto h-56 bg-img-header offset-navbar relative">
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
    <h1 id="sectiontext" class="font-merriweather tracking-wider text-shadow-black font-bold text-gray-300 text-center uppercase text-6xl absolute transform-center text-"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
//loads pageheader and footer on pages//
$(function() {
  $("#navigation").load("/navbar.html");
  $("#pageheader").load("/pageheader.html");
  $("#footer").load("/footer.html");
});

//replaces the text in the page header with the page's title//
var x = document.title;

function titleInjection() {
  document.getElementById("sectiontext").textContent = x;
}
```

***NOTE: I used to have the variable defined after I called the function, but I saw another answer on here that suggested I should define that first. It helped go from 1 page header loading correctly to about 2 - 3, so I left it like this. I also tried to simplify this by writing `document.getElementById("sectiontext").textContent = document.title;}` but that also didn't work.

TLDR: I'm using innerHTML/TextContent to change my web page and it only works sporadically.

Comment: Are you changing the title dynamically?

Comment: You have to understand Asynchronous behavior of Events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` is asynchronous. So when you're trying to find the `sectiontext` element, it doesn't exist yet because `.load("/pageheader.html");` hasn't completed. You should call `titleInjection()` from its callback.

```
$(function() {
  $("#navigation").load("/navbar.html");
  $("#pageheader").load("/pageheader.html", titleInjection);
  $("#footer").load("/footer.html");
});
```

Comment: You're amazing sir. Thank you for your quick reply @Barmar. Now that the site is fixed I have time to read up asynchronous JavaScript.